# Combining 'AND , 'OR' in Select statement

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Studentname: When the user enters Id or name and click button, the details should be displyaed....How?

Here my OR clause is not working in the select statement:

```
public partial class StudentView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = "SELECT Registration.UsrFLname, Registration.UsrAddress, Students.STUID, Materials.BookID, Materials.BookName, Courses.CourseName, Courses.CourseFee FROM Courses INNER JOIN Materials ON Courses.BookID = Materials.BookID INNER JOIN Students ON Courses.STUID = Students.STUID AND Materials.STUID = Students.STUID INNER JOIN Registration ON Students.STUID = Registration.STUID AND Registration.UsrFLname = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' OR Students.STUID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, str);
        GDStudents.DataSource = ds;
        GDStudents.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help on this issue!!

Thank in advance!!

Comment: Define "not working". Also, you have a SQL Injection security flaw in this code.

Comment: For the love of god, use parameterized queries!

Comment: Also, have you found the Enter/Return key on your keyboard? And have you heard of SQL injection?

Comment: Wrap the two parts left and right of the OR in parentheses ().

Comment: Hold on... let me stop eating my lunch to do your job for you.  I love answering questions, but really, this looks like you didn't give it the old "college" try before giving up and posting here.

Comment: It would probably read better with a where clause as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` has a higher priority than `OR`.

In boolean logic `AND` is like multiplication and `OR` is like summation, hence, when you want summation to happen before multiplication, you should use parentheses `()`.

I.e.

```
2*3+1 = 7
2*(3+1) = 8
```

I guess in your case, the condition should be

```
Students.STUID = Registration.STUID 
   AND 
( -- note this paren
    Registration.UsrFLname = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' 
        OR
    Students.STUID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
) -- note this paren
```

As many people noted, you should parameterize your queries, and do not inject text supplied by the end user.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you aren't getting the results you're expecting because you're not grouping your boolean operations correctly, you have `X AND Y OR Z` when you mean `X AND (Y OR Z)`. In the case of the former, only Z or the combination of X and Y need be true in order for the entire expression to evaluate to true.

On a different note, the code you have here is **wide open** to a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack, which is [real bad](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). You should switch this to a [parameterized query](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx) posthaste.